# Excel UserForm Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a code to Insert Project Costs on a Worksheet. I am not an Excel Expert so I am using this tutorial to guide me: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO10WZ2prDQ (it's in Portuguese, but you can see what the UserForm does within the first minute of the video)

What I want to do is insert costs in a worksheet and then filter them to generate a report of all project costs and their categories.

Here's my UserForm: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIzwT.png

When coding for the Insert Button ('Inserir Custo'), here's what I typed:

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Plan4")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.ListBox1.Value

ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value

Me.ListBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
```

Excel shows an error on the iRow line of the code, but I dont know whats wrong. When clicking that button, I want the code to insert the results of the ListBox1 in a cell, and the TextBox1 in another cell, next to it.

Can someone help me? What did I write wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Use this to define `iRow` instead: `iRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: You will get that error if there's no content on the "Plan4" worksheet.

Comment: what is the error that you get? what is the name of your worksheet?

Comment: @tigeravatar, your method only works if column A always has data when the other cells have data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FoundIt As Range


Set ws = Worksheets("Plan4")
Set FoundIt = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)

If FoundIt Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox ("nothing found")
Else

  iRow = FoundIt.Row + 1
  ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.ListBox1.Value
  ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
  Me.ListBox1.Value = ""
  Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
  Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

The problem is, if the find function doesn't get a match it returns a nothing value and then you try to get the row number from nothing.. My code above simplifies it a bit and only tries to get the row number if it is a valid range.

Comment: Hello, perfo. Thanks for answering. Your code works, but it's not inserting the investment category, only its value. I would like to insert both. If you wanna check my userform style again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIzwT.png Thanks!

Comment: The original question was about the error in your code. My code fixed that so you should accept my answer as correct. I didn't attempt to alter the functionality of your code , only fix the error. The question you have now should really be posted as a different question however the values in the listbox wont be transferred unless you click on one. Are you just scrolling down the list and not selecting one  before pressing the insert button ?

Comment: Thanks. Did clicking on the list item also solve your other problem? If you prefer you can have a list auto select the top item unless someone changes it. YOu can't just scroll up and down and press the insert you need to click on a list item before insert...

Answer (score 0):

you need to start search at A1, because you are searching in UP direction from there, which rolls over to bottom of sheet and keeps going up until it hits data

```
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=ws.range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rw As Range, f As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Plan4")
Set f = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not f Is Nothing Then 
    Set rw = f.Offset(1,0).EntireRow
Else
    Set rw = ws.Rows(1)
End If

With rw
    .Cells(1).Value = Me.ListBox1.Value
    .Cells(2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
End With

Me.ListBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
```